# how to check data is present or not in xamarin database

Tags: xamarin.android

Hello everyone i Have implemented sqlite database in xamarin and i need to search taht any specfic data is present or not in database.

I want to check that if data or row is there or not in database according to the album key

Here is my Database class

```
namespace FacebookAuth
{
    class DatabaseHelper
    {
        Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Android/data/com.abhijit.testing.app/databases");

        public bool createDataBase()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
                {
                    connection.CreateTable<AlbumTable>();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool InsertIntoTable(AlbumTable album)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Console.Write("Data Saved Successfully");

                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
                {
                    connection.Insert(album);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public List<AlbumTable> getalldata()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
                {
                    return connection.Table<AlbumTable>().ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public List<AlbumTable> SelectAlbum(string orderid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
                {
                    return connection.Query<AlbumTable>("SELECT * From album Where AlbumKey=?", orderid);//not working exception raised that invalid table name
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool DeleteFromTable(AlbumTable album)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Console.Write("Data Saved Successfully");

                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
                {
                    connection.Delete(album);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the column name for database is as follows

```
K
class AlbumTable
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ZipFillPath { get; set; }

    public string CoverPhotoPath { get; set; }

    public string AlbumKey { get; set; }

    public string NoOfPages { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

How to check that value is present in db or not

Comment: As a first step you should add a new method getAlbum(string albumKey) to class DatabaseHelper. The returntype must be AlbumTable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Android Device Monitor` from `Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor`
   [image]
2. Navigate to your database file and copy out the database file into your PC.
   [image]
3. You can open the database using any SQLite browser to check whether your data is in the DB. e.g. http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: I want to do it problematically sir

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) are quite good at giving easy-to-follow instructions.

You need your id column to be an `int`, then you can use the `Get<T>()` method

```
public List<AlbumTable> SelectAlbum(int orderid)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dir.AbsolutePath, "album.db")))
        {
            return connection.Get<AlbumTable>(orderid);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you wish to use Sql (see next point as to why you may want to), you need to create the table with a defined name, otherwise the name given to the table may well be some programmatically-created non-human-friendly internal gibberish.

```
[Table("Albums")]
class AlbumTable
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
...
```

If you have to keep the id column as a string (that is you have no control over the database) you could use a linq get

```
return connection.Get<AlbumTable>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == orderid);
```

Note that this loads all the data into memory and so will be horrible for performance if you get a large amount of data in the database as well as loosing the inbuilt advantages of databases - storing and searching data is what they are built for.  This is not Entity Framework and so for complex queries, use direct Sql statements as above.

Comment: In class `AlbumTable`, change `public string Id { get; set; }` to `public int Id { get; set; }` and use `return connection.Get<AlbumTable>(orderid);` (where `orderid` is an `int`).